# Where do I play "The Shell Game"?

Tags: watch-dogs

Under the "progression" menu in Watch Dogs, there is an upgrade:

> **Beat 3 levels of the Shell Game** - XP bonus for improving Aiden's street smarts

I want bonus XP!

However, I don't see The Shell Game in any of the mini-game menus in my phone.  **Where do I go to play the Shell Game?**

Comment: It's a physical shell game run by a physical person: http://www.ign.com/wikis/watch-dogs/Minigames

Comment: Yes I saw that page, but it doesn't tell you where to find it, and/or how to unlock it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft if you open a map, you will see a lot of icons there. Just hover over them and one of them(actually more) will be *The Shell Game*

Comment: @Novarg: If you put that into an answer *(with an example of what the icon looks like, and where I can find one)*, I'd accept it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I would, but somebody already did that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mini-game that you can find in many places around the town. It's shown on the minimap with an icon of a cup.
[image]

Comment: @James' answer has more detailed information to go with the screenshot I provided :)

Answer (score 5):

An even better trick is to relax (you don't even have to look at the screen), let him do his thing and then when it's time to pick, pause the game, the x-ray vision will let you see which cup the ball is in!

Comment: Increasing the luminosity can help to see the ball.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: These locations are actually Unlocked when you free gain access to the ctOS towers. They are parts of the points of interest that will then become available within the area showing up as the dice icons as mentioned before along with other points of interest in the vicinity.

As you roam around the city you will eventually come across people all over the place who want to play this game. They are denoted on the minimap (and likely map) with the symbol of Dice on them.

After that you are on your own in how to play, its simple. Watch them put the ball under a cup and the try to keep track of it as best you can to pick the right one. The game has ranks that keep getting more and more expensive as you play.

UPDATE: As pointed out by @Philipp in the comments, you can still use your focus to slow time during this game to help you track the movement better.

Comment: A trick which might not be obvious is that your ability to enter slow-motion is not disabled during the shell-game. While you don't have enough focus-energy to play the whole game in slow motion, you can use it to slow down particularily confusing moments.