# How do I beat "Shell Game" in Watch Dogs?

Tags: watch-dogs

I have been trying to beat the mini-game "Shell Game" for so long. The last level rewards an experience multiplier, but past mid way, I am hopeless at keeping up with the ball.

Is there any really simple way to beat this game, without tedious trial and error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I play "The Shell Game"?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170062/how-do-i-play-the-shell-game)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I had thought so too, when I came across the question earlier. The question asks how to play in context of **how do I start the game**; the asker basically asks where the game is, on the map, and mentions nothing about actually playing the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the NPC finishes switching the cups around, and asks you to find the ball, simply pause the game.

[image: The Shell Game, paused to show the outlines.]

While the game is paused, all game models will be outlined. You can see the faint outline of the ball 90% of the time, and guarantee which cup to select without even watching the transition.

In the above image, you can see the faint outline inside the middle cup. At default settings, only 2 instances were not clearly visible. Both were when the ball was in the left cup.